# Dynamically created variables in for loop

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

Is it possible to use a for loop to dynamically name variables? Something such as:

```
t = {} 

For i in ipairs(tablename) do
   t.i = something
End
```

My actual problem consists of dynamically creating protofields for a wireshark dissector, but if the above is not possible, I doubt the protofield problem will be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `t[i]`. This will index the table (`t`) with a value `i`.

```
local t = {}

for i, _ in ipairs(othertbl) do
    t[i] = something
end
```

(Note that in Lua, `foo.bar` is short for `foo["bar"]`. Also note that the string `"123"` is different from the number `123`)

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly understand your problem, but try following:

```
t = {}

for i in ipairs(tablename) do
    _G["t"][i] = tablename[i];
end
```

Or if you mean (I think that you mean) to create variable name containing number:

```
 local tablename = {"a", "b"}

 for i in ipairs(tablename) do
      _G["t"..i] = tablename[i];
 end
```

So you have "t1", "t2" variable.

_G[name] is used global variables (at least in Runes of Magic).

If _G[name] returning error, try setglobal(name) instead.

Comment: The example table that I have is a multi-dementional table, ~37 entries. I was hoping to be able to loop through the table and create a variable for each entry, which will later be used to create a wireshark protofield. So at the end, I would have a variable t.1 through t.37 that can then be used in a dissector

Comment: `_G["t"]` is silly. Just do `t`, i.e. `t[i]`. Also there's no such function as `setglobal` in vanilla Lua.